# Fixing delay issue in java keypress action

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

I am creating a Java application that uses the keylistener. I have noticed that when using the keypressed listener when the user is holding down the key, it registers and then takes a second to detect the hold. Is there a way to get rid of this short delay?

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) 
{
    char key = arg0.getKeyChar();
    if(key == 'a')
        update = Status.Left;
    else if(key == 's')
        update = Status.Crouch;
    else if(key == 'd')
        update = Status.Right;
    else if(key == ' ')
        update = Status.Shoot;
    else
        update = Status.None;
    System.out.println(arg0.getKeyChar());
    this.repaint();
}
```

Comment: Just double checking -- this is an AWT application not a Swing application, correct? Because if Swing, I'd have a solution -- to use a Swing Timer and key bindings.

Comment: @DazSlayer : KeyEvent is for awt not Swing. Swing has [KeyBinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). Do read a bit about them also. They are more appropriate then KeyEvent.   Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you don't detect the hold using the keyPressed event. Use a timer to constantly check for pressed keys. Use a BitSet. On keyPressed and on keyReleased update the BitSet to keep track of the pressed keys. This way you can detect multiple key presses at once.
If you are building a game you already have the game clock which could be used for this

Answer (score 1):

I think these events are generated by the JVM / operating system. The user has to change the key-delay / key-repeat settings for eliminating the delay.

I don't think there is a way to control delay through code.